# Deleted a triggered webjob but function still running continuously

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I've deleted triggered Webjob on Azure WebApp, but the Function is still running and sending Webhook data. I can't seem to delete it. Why is this function does not get deleted?
How do I stop it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `Web Job` might be running in the background.

Get the list of running `Web Jobs` using the `Azure CLI` command.

I have taken references from the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/continuous?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-webjob-continuous-list).

Use the below command to get the list of continuous Web Jobs.

```cs
az webapp webjob continuous list --name WebApplication17Apr --resource-group YourRGName
```

[image]

If you still feel you `Web Job` is not deleted and running, delete it by using the `Azure CLI` command.

```cs
az webapp webjob continuous remove --name WebApplication17Apr --resource-group YourRGName --webjob-name ContinuousJob
```

- Initially I got 2 Web Jobs in the list.

***Before deleting the `Web Job`:***

[image]

- After running the remove Web Job command, you can see only one web Job is available.

[image]

***After deleting `ContinuousJob`:***
[image]

- We can see the entry itself is deleted completely.

Even you can stop a WebJob by using [`az webapp webjob continuous stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/continuous?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-webjob-continuous-stop) command.